# update key in nested object

Tags: mongodb

I have a document that have another doc as value of "basicInfo" field:

```
{
  "personId": "5b45b3700fdd1a14c9f",
  "basicInfo": {
    "name": "dave",
    "age": 25,
    "personAddress": {
      "city": "los angeles",
      "street": "hollywood",
      "streetNumber": 150,
      "zipCode": 90210
    },
    "active": true
  }
}
```

im trying to only update the person name with this:

```
db.people.findAndModify({
    query: { "personId" : "5b45b3700fdd1a14c9f" },
    update: {"$set":{"basicInfo":{"name":"new name"}}}
})
```

and that is replacing basic info...i want to create a method that will send a json with the fields user want to change and just those fields will be changed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use .dot notation to update the nested `name`
 field

```
db.people.findAndModify({
    query: { "personId": "5b45b3700fdd1a14c9f" },
    update: { "$set": {"basicInfo.name": "new name" } } }
})
```